# awk / sed script to remove text

Tags: text, scripting, sed, makefile, awk

I am currently in need of a way to programmatically remove some text from Makefiles that I am dealing with. Now the problem is that (for whatever reason) the makefiles are being generated with link commands of `-l<full_path_to_library>/<library_name>` when they should be generated with `-l<library_name>`. So what I need is a script to find all occurrences of `-l/` and then remove up to and including the next `/`.

Example of what I'm dealing with

> -l/home/user/path/to/boost/lib/boost_filesystem

I need it to be

> -lboost_filesystem

As could be imagined this is a stop gap measure until I fix the real problem (on the generation side) but in the meantime it would be a great help to me if this could work and I am not too good with my awk and sed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not tackling the problem of *why* the build system is making screwed up makefiles in the first place?

Comment: As stated in the question this is a stop-gap solution. I am currently running an unofficial patch of the build system that has certain features that I need, unfortunately it is generating makefiles with the stated problem. I definitely intend to fix the issue (and soon) by properly integrating the new features but in the meantime I wanted to be able to compile my application, after days of getting everything set up and now I can ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i 's|-l[^ ]*/\([^/ ]*\)|-l\1|g' Makefile
```

Comment: I'd add whitespace in front of the `-l` to avoid matching `-lrelative-librarypath/lib`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
echo "-l/home/user/path/to/boost/lib/boost_filesystem" | awk -F"/" '{ print $1  $NF  } '
```

Comment: That handles your single test case, but not the general problem of multiple instances on lines containing other text. awk is happiest on line actions, you could add a pattern to the scriptlette but sed is the better choice here.